# How to make my wpf app wait for 3 minutes before re-loading data?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using VS2010 - WPF - C#

in my application I fetch data from a web server and view it on my interface
the problem is that I want to keep fetching data and keep refreshing my interface every 3 minutes but I don't know how to do that...

I tried (Thread.Sleep(18000)) and it didn't work because my interface wouldn't show at all

I don't know how to use the Timer for such reason and I couldn't find what I'm looking for elsewhere

Please can you help me with it ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What programming model? Stock or something more sane with a MVVM approach?

Anyhow, use a TIMER to request a callback after 3 minutes. In the callback invoke back to the dispatcher thread of the window once you got the results of the web service call. Finished.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), there are also examples how to use it on the given link

Answer (score 0):

Use a dispatch timer like this

> Delcare it

```
public System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer1;
```

> In the constructor

```
timer1 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180); // 3 mintues interval
timer1.Tick += TimerTicked; // Event for handling the fetching data
```

> Do your job

```
 private void TimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
//Fetch the data
 }
```

timer1.start(); // Whereever you want to start the timer